# How to set time format for Camunda engine

Tags: mysql, camunda

The Camunda engine of my app writes history of activities/processes (to DB, i use mysql) with precision of seconds:
[image: activities history table]

But it's necessary to store it with **milliseconds** accuracy.
There is no such property in [engine config](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.16/reference/deployment-descriptors/tags/process-engine/) doc, but i definitely know, that Camunda can use msec too.

Appreciate any ideas.

Comment: You can [alter the table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html) and make `START_TIME_` and `END_TIME_` have a fsp precision [per manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-type-syntax.html) (3 for milliseconds, up to 6(microseconds) supported). It would be useful to show the data ypes of these two columns from `SHOW CREATE TABLE tblname`.